# Rails Mailer custom dynamic content

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, email, dynamic, actionmailer

I've recently joined a project where each client has their own custom HTML content for emails sent to their customers.

It does this by inserting the content into the string with custom tags, and then sent by setting the body attribute in a mailer, like so:

```
mail(:from         => from_email,
     :reply_to     => from_email,
     :to           => to_email,
     :subject      => subject,
     :body         => (html_text.empty?) ? plain_text : html_text,
     :content_type => (html_text.empty?) ? 'text/plain' : 'text/html',
    )
```

One functionality to be added was the inclusion of inline images; however - by manually setting the content_type to be either 'text/plain' or 'text/html', the email cannot be rendered properly, and the image cannot be attached correctly either (the content_type of the overall email seems to mess up):
 [image: messed up content_type email].

On removing this explicit content_type, the image is correctly attached, yet the inline image is not  displayed (the place holder is swapped out for an image_tag using the attached image), as the content does not seem to be interpreted as HTML, for example the content of the email is:

```
Dolor eligendi doloremque et.
<img alt="Signature Image" src="cid:5225b25b53818_b4213fc5ce0349d0975f@localhost.mail" />
```

How do I get the email to correctly interpret the content as HTML without messing up the inline image content type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even for dynamic content; let rails do the heavy lifting for you. Passing the content into an empty view template to be rendered rather than passing a body to the mail method means that all your content types are set implicitly.

Afterwards, the mailer should not pass the content directly, leaving you with only:

```
mail(:from         => from_email,
     :reply_to     => from_email,
     :to           => to_email,
     :subject      => subject
     )
```

Or try this,

```
 mail(:from => from_email,:reply_to => from_email) do |format|
       format.html { render 'another_template' }
       format.text { render 'another_template' }
 end
```

It will create a multipart email that includes both html and text parts. This will allow text only clients to render it using that part and html based clients to render it properly too.

Comment: The content isn't being set from a view; and image tags are being generated properly to be displayed, but they're not being rendered as it's interpreting the content as text, not html.

Comment: No.. I'm saying, use mail(:from         => from_email,
     :reply_to     => from_email,
     :to           => to_email,
     :subject      => subject) in ur mailer. In your view, add the image content. The content can be separated from the mailer method.

Comment: So create two views, one for both plain text, and the other for html, set the content inside the view to simply be the string passed in - say `@content.html_safe`

Comment: Thanks - I was too caught up in their current way of doing it to take a step back and evaluate the overall situation. Can you re-phrase your original answer and I'll mark it as correct?